# Using Cast as Decimal and Mod in Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

My objective is to perform two calculations on two selected fields.  The  `formActionDate` is an integer like so `YYYMMDD` and `reminderFrequency` is also an integer (a whole number representing a number of days).  I am wanting to divide the integer date by the number of days.  Using mod (I think this is the best approach) I will decide if an email needs to go out.  EG if there is a left over then dont send email or if there is no left over an email goes out.  Using **SQL 2008 R2** I have this in my select:

```
SELECT 
      CAST(wfi.formActionDate/wf.reminderFrequency AS DECIMAL(18,1)) AS divCalc, 
      formActionDate%reminderFrequency AS modCalc
FROM (webFormsInstances AS wfi
```

> **Note** - The query is running no problem but the calculations are both
>   out.  Have I used them correctly?

The first one:

```
CAST(wfi.formActionDate/wf.reminderFrequency AS DECIMAL(18,3)) AS divCalc
```

Is doing this:
As a result of : `20150123 / 14` which should be `1439294.5` but its `1439294.0`
and            `20150115 / 14` which should be `1439293.9` nut its `1439293.0`

and then the second one::

```
formActionDate%reminderFrequency AS modCalc
```

To use the same examples above:
As a result of : `20150123%14` which should be `5` but its `13`
and            `20150115%14` which should be `9` but its `7`

What have I done wrong?  Here is my full query if it helps:

```
SELECT 
      wfi.WebFormsInstanceID, 
      wfi.WebFormsIndexID, 
      wfi.FormStage,
      wfi.FormAction, 
      wfi.FormActionDate, 
      wf.WebFormsIndexID, 
      wf.reminderFrequency,
      CAST(wfi.formActionDate/wf.reminderFrequency AS DECIMAL(18,1)) AS divCalc, 
      formActionDate%reminderFrequency AS modCalc
FROM (webFormsInstances AS wfi
LEFT OUTER JOIN WebFormsIndex AS wf ON wfi.WebFormsIndexID = wf.WebFormsIndexID)
WHERE (wfi.formStage <> 'Complete' AND wfi.FormStage <> 'Terminated') 
AND wfi.formActionDate < CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varchar(8), dateAdd(day,-14, getdate()), 112))
ORDER BY wfi.WebFormsInstanceID DESC;
```

Thanking You...

Edited.  Thanks to Rigel1121 and Dave G The two solutions which are now in my select are:

```
DATEDIFF(day, CAST(CAST(wfi.formActionDate AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE),CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS theDateDiffCalc,
```

and:

```
DATEDIFF(day, CAST(CAST(wfi.formActionDate AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE),CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) % wf.reminderFrequency AS theModCalc
```

Comment: Think about sending email every other day, i.e. using a frequency of 2. What happens at the end of the month? The next month will start with an odd value, i.e. day 1, but how does the current month end? You may get two odd values in a row, which doesn't work with your mod method. DavidG has the answer: convert to a count of days from some base date and then apply mod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By checking your query there is an unnecessary parenthesis. So I removed it. I've also modified it on how you will get the value of `divCalc`. I `CAST` both the numerator and the denominator and I put it in `CASE` statement to prevent the SQL Error when the value of`wf.reminderFrequency` is zero. Also I used the `DATEDIFF` function to get the `modCalc`. See below:

```
SELECT 
      wfi.WebFormsInstanceID, 
      wfi.WebFormsIndexID, 
      wfi.FormStage,
      wfi.FormAction, 
      wfi.FormActionDate, 
      wf.WebFormsIndexID, 
      wf.reminderFrequency,
      CASE WHEN CAST(wf.reminderFrequency AS DECIMAL(18,1))=0.0 THEN 0.0 ELSE CAST(wfi.formActionDate AS DECIMAL(18,1)) / CAST(wf.reminderFrequency AS DECIMAL(18,1)) END as divCalc, 
     DATEDIFF(DAY, '2000-01-01', CAST(CAST(wfi.formActionDate AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE)%wf.reminderFrequency as modCalc
      FROM webFormsInstances as wfi
LEFT OUTER JOIN WebFormsIndex as wf ON wfi.WebFormsIndexID = wf.WebFormsIndexID
WHERE (wfi.formStage <> 'Complete' AND wfi.FormStage <> 'Terminated') 
AND wfi.formActionDate < CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varchar(8), dateAdd(day,-14, getdate()), 112))
ORDER BY wfi.WebFormsInstanceID DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you.  your 'CASE WHEN CAST' line does resolve my first issue.  My second issue however is still there.  MOD is not part of tsql allowed in the SQLServer world.  Its equivalent is supposed to be % as I have used in my original post.  So my issue 2 remains.  Why is 20150115%14 returning 7 when it should be 5?

Comment: I had just tried this.  It turns 7 into 7.0 unfortunately.   I have just found out another problem I may have.  My end objective is to use the result of modCalc in the where clause.  Having it in the select was my way of building it up.  Once modCalc is correct I would like to add AND modCalc = 0.   Can I use this result of a SELECT calculation in the where clause?  Another way of describing my end objective is to only get records that have no remainder.  Thanking you

Comment: Ok. i have not been thinking properly.  This %(MOD) is supposed to give the remainder and not the fractional part of the equation.  my bad!  This would make it correct, what was I thinking...  The modCalc result is correct.   My last task is to use this in the WHERE clause.  I would like to limit my result set, adding AND modCalc = 0.  This doesnt seem possible.  Is some kind of sub query required?

Comment: You can use the formula itself in where clause such as : AND formActionDate%reminderFrequency=0.

Comment: With regards to you're second problem, use the answer of @DavidG.

Answer (score 2):

When you divide an `int` with another `int`, the result will also be an `int`. You need to cast either one or both of the parameters to `decimal` first. For example:

```
SELECT CAST(wfi.formActionDate AS DECIMAL(18,1)) / 
       CAST(wf.reminderFrequency AS DECIMAL(18,1)) as divCalc
...snip...
```

And regarding the `mod` calculation, your maths is not going to work with dates in that format. You need to convert that `int` to a real `datetime` value, get the difference of that from a base date and then use `mod` on that value. For example, to get that value as a date, you can convert it to a `varchar` first, then cast that as `date`:

```
DECLARE @datevalue int = 20150209

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2000-01-01', CAST(CAST(@datevalue AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE))%14
```

Comment: @ DavidG Thank you.  Looks like the same tack as Rigel has used below with the first part of my issue.  I dont understand your second suggestion.  formActionDate and reminderFrequency are both integers, why would I need to covert to date?  Surely I can get the MOD (or equivalent) of two integers?

Comment: @Mat41 Well unless you use my method, your arithmetic will not work for consecutive days that span over month boundaries. For example, run the logic over `20150131` (which is 31st January) then `20150201` which is the next day (1st February).

Comment: Yes as you know you are 100% correct. when I looked at the more closely I realized your method was essential. I have updated my initial post with the end solution which is a mixture of yours and Rigel1121 contributions

Comment: No problem, glad you got your answer. Don't forget you can change your accepted answer too... Just kidding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the cast before the division, instead of afterward. Instead of

```
CAST(wfi.formActionDate/wf.reminderFrequency AS DECIMAL(18,1))
```

use

```
wfi.formActionDate/CAST(wf.reminderFrequency AS DECIMAL(18,1))
```

Division with two integers results in an integer (truncating any fractional part). For example, `SELECT 5 / 2;` is `2` (it is not `2.5`). If you cast the result of the division (`2`) to `DECIMAL(3,1)`, you will get `2.0` because the truncation happened as part of the division.

However, if you cast one of the operands to a decimal before the division, the result of the division won't be an integer and won't lose the fractional part. `SELECT 5 / CAST(2 as DECIMAL(3,1));` is `2.5`.

For the mod, `20150123 % 14` should result in 7 and `20150115 % 14` should result in 13, and in my testing they do.